Hot water knocking and surging in the back shower then stop
I opened the hot water faucet in the shower and it started knocking and surging and then stopped flowing. How do I go about fixing this?

Is this your home or a rental? If you are renting your first call is to your landlord. If this is your home please edit your question to be an actual question.
